# Better style in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, coding-style, conventions

I have several queries that look like this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM people 
WHERE id IN (SELECT person_id 
             FROM directors 
             WHERE movie_id IN (SELECT id 
                                FROM movies 
                                WHERE id IN (SELECT movie_id 
                                             FROM ratings 
                                             WHERE rating = 10)));
```

It works, but I don't think that nesting so many queries will work in the long term, readability-wise. What is the convention on how to write that in a more legible way? Would you just use one line for every query?

Comment: In many cases you can JOIN instead of having IN subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

```
SELECT name 
FROM people  p 
join directors d on d.person_id = p.id
join movies m on m.id = d.movie_id 
join ratings  r on r.movie_id = m.id
WHERE r.rating = 10
```

Comment: That looks quite cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My personal way of formatting SQL statements is to indent using 2 spaces. I've found this improves readability [to me]. For example:

```
SELECT name 
FROM people 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT person_id 
  FROM directors 
  WHERE movie_id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM movies 
    WHERE id IN (
      SELECT movie_id 
      FROM ratings 
      WHERE rating = 10
    )
  )
);
```